# Error during PDF form population, how do I fix and display pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdftk, pdf-form

I am trying to populate a pdf form using the example posted here:

https://www.adamalbrecht.com/blog/2014/01/31/pre-filling-pdf-form-templates-in-ruby-on-rails-with-pdftk/

I am trying to answer 2 questions..

1. What is causing the error?
2. And simply how do I execute this in my user show.html.erb?

#app/pdfs/fillablepdfform.rb

```
class FillablePdfForm

    attr_writer :template_path
    attr_reader :attributes
  
    def initialize
      fill_out
    end
  
    def export(output_file_path=nil)
      output_path = output_file_path || "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdfs/#{SecureRandom.uuid}.pdf" # make sure tmp/pdfs exists
      pdftk.fill_form template_path, output_path, attributes
      output_path
    end
  
    def get_field_names 
      pdftk.get_field_names template_path
    end
  
    def template_path
      @template_path ||= "#{Rails.root}/lib/pdf_templates/EmployeeFormFillable.pdf" # makes assumption about template file path unless otherwise specified
    end
  
    protected
  
    def attributes
      @attributes ||= {}
    end
  
    def fill(key, value)
      attributes[key.to_s] = value
    end
  
    def pdftk
      @pdftk ||= PdfForms.new(ENV['PDFTK_PATH'] || '/usr/local/bin/pdftk') # On my Mac, the location of pdftk was different than on my linux server.
      Rails.logger.info @pdftk
    end
  
    def fill_out
      raise 'Must be overridden by child class'
    end
  
  end
```

#app/controllers/testpdfform_controller.rb

```
class TestpdfformController < FillablePdfForm

    def initialize(user)
        @user = user
        super()
      end
    
      protected

      def fill_out
        [:firstname, :lastname].each do |field|
          fill field, @user.send(field)
        end

      end

end
```

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def new
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf { send_file TestPdfForm.new(@user).export, type: 'application/pdf' }
        end
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            #flash[:notice] = "Book saved"
            redirect_to @user , notice: 'User Saved'
            # flash[:notice] = "Book Saved."
            #redirect_to action: 'index', notice: 'Book Saved'
        else
            render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname)
    end

end
```

#config/initializers/mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

[image]

Comment: The most likely reason for this is that the incoming request has the wrong accept or content type headers or is missing an extension. Look at the Rails logs - it will most likely contain something like `Processing by UsersController#show AS HTML`. You can force the format by adding a `.pdf` extension to the URL. This can be done by passing the `format` option to the routing helpers. eg. `<%= link_to 'PDF', user_path(@user, format: :pdf) %>`.

Comment: I would also be aware of the age of that tutorial. 2014 was a long time ago and while there are some nifty things like the `fill` mini DSL its pretty long in the tooth.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The log did show Processing by UsersController#show as HTML. Your recommendation fixed that issue though. Now its showing an "uninitialized constant FillablePdfForm::PdfForms" and I think its related to ENV['PDFTK_PATH']. Looks like its pulling the path but maybe I have the wrong one set in my windows environment variables. Should the path end up at a pdftk.rb file or is there another executable file?

Comment: I think this is actually an error in the tutorial. It references a constant that doesn't exist and this doesn't really have anything to do with PDFTK library which doesn't include any Ruby code as far as I know. Then again I dunno who you're using a tutorial from 2014 for a lib that got its last stable release back then instead of more accepted solutions like Prawn.

Comment: So the application Im supporting is Ruby 2.2.5 and Rails 4.2, it uses this pdftk library so Im just trying to replicate the environment locally so I can do some testing.

Comment: Looking through the code I do see Prawn referenced several places so it must use it as well.